# Ctrl-C will cause remote connect closed on chromium adb_gdb debugging (for android)

Tags: android, gdb, chromium

I can use adb_gdb to attach chromium app on device, it can work successfully. But when I tried to enter ctrl-c to interrupt gdb and enter some breakpoint, the gdb server will close connection...

Did anyone know why this happened?

I did set interrupt command, but it did not help:

set remotebreak
set remote interrupt-sequence Ctrl-C